# How to implement OAuth in ReactJS and Spring Security?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

How could I implement `OAuth Google` authentication using `ReactJS and axios`?
I have following http security configuration:

```
   @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .mvcMatchers("/", "login/**", "/js/**", "/error**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }
```

I login by `localhost:8080` successfully, but on `localhost:3000` my user is not authenticated after that http request.

Comment: You need an interceptor for telling Spring Security that authentication exists. See  https://github.com/locationguru-solutions/web-application-reference/blob/master/web-application/src/main/java/config/SecurityConfiguration.java and https://github.com/locationguru-solutions/web-application-reference/blob/master/web-application/src/main/java/config/support/JwtTokenFilter.java#L50

Comment: @KedarJoshi ufff ,hard) I have no tokens, etc. I just have OAuth authentication.

Comment: The source or type of authentication is immaterial. All Spring Security needs is this `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);` i.e. some sort of authentication in its security context.

Comment: @KedarJoshi nono, i Have OAuth2, its ok

Comment: @KedarJoshi so I just need to add this code to my securityconfig and :3000 will see that user is authenticated?

Comment: Oops wrong link. This might help https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/

Comment: thanks, will read @KedarJoshi